# Atypical intersection of algebraic varieties

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

We know that if $X, Y\subset \mathbb{A}^n$ are irreducible closed subvarieties and we assume that $X\cap Y$ is non empty, then each irreducible component of $X\cap Y$ has dimension **at least** $\dim{X}+\dim{Y}- n$. But when talking about unlikely (atypical) intersections we move to the other side of the inequality:

In Umberto Zannier's book "Some Problems of Unlikely Intersections in Arithmetic and Geometry", in the very first pages we study the motivation to this field:
[image]

Why would we expect the opposite of the above theorem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In addition to the answer, one may note that by the moving lemma of intersection theory, it is always possible to find a cycle $Z$ on the space, which is rationally equivalent to $X$ and whose components intersect $Y$ in varieties of dimension $r+s-n$. So up to deformation (in some sense), this is the situation of intersection theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that this is not completely the opposite of the theorem you quoted. The part

> in particular to be empty if $r+s<n$.

is exactly a consequence of your theorem, when the intersection takes place in $\mathbb A^n$ (and similar theorems hold in $\mathbb P^n$). So the question is: Why do we expect $\dim X \cap Y = r+s-n$ in the "general case"?

I think one motivation comes from linear algebra. If $r+s \geq n$, then two subspaces $V_1, V_2 \subset V$ of dimensions $r,s$ have an intersection of dimension $r+s-n$ if and only if $V_1 + V_2 = V$. But $r+s$ "general" vectors will generate $V$.

A less basic motivation might come from differential topology. Two manifolds $X,Y  \subset Z$ are said to intersect transversely in a point $p \in X \cap Y$, if and only if their tangent spaces in $p$ generate the tangent space of $Z$, i.e.
$$T_pX + T_pY = T_pZ.$$
Here you see the connection to the linear algebra case. Now there are important transversality theorems in differential topology, that you can always move the manifolds in such a way that they intersect transversely in every intersection point. So transverse intersections are the generic case also for manifolds.

Comment: Oh I see! so apparently I misunderstood the “atypical” part. Thank you!